# Java: Upload files to dropbox

Tags: java, file-upload, dropbox, dropbox-api

So i have a simple problem and am looking for a few pointers to a simple solution. I have a java app that must upload a file to dropbox. It will know the username and password of the dropbox account to upload to by default. All i need now is some way to put a file on my computer in any directory on to the dropbox in any directory of the dropbox. I've downloaded the dropbox API for java but am completely lost as to what to do with it. Can somebody please hand me the rod and point me the right way as to how to upload files to dropbox using java and preferably the dropbox API (and i think thats the only way to...is to use the dropbox java api). Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Did you read the [developer documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/docs)? If you know REST, most of that documentation is self-explanatory.